# Quantlib Bond yield jump on front end of the curve

Tags: quantlib, yield-curve

I'm trying to build up a US treasury curves using Bills and bonds with the FixedRateBond class, however when I compared the ParYield from .bondYield() and zero_rate from yield curve instance.
The yield has large monthly jump in very front end (<1Y), but the zero rate looks smooth..

I check that curve.zeroRate(ql.Date(20, 11, 2023), day_count, ql.Compounded) looks normal ->5.42%
however the discount factor from curve gives large implied rate:
(1/curve.discount(ql.Date(20, 11, 2023)))**(365/(16))

Is there a bug in Quantlib bondYield() method..?

```
calc_date = ql.Date(today,'%Y%m%d')
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date
bump = 50 # bps

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
bussiness_convention = ql.Unadjusted
day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.Bond)
end_of_month = False
settlement_days = 1
face_amount = 100
coupon_frequency = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

depo_helpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(r/100.0)),
                                     m,
                                     settlement_days,
                                     calendar,
                                     bussiness_convention,
                                     end_of_month,
                                     day_count )
                for r, m in zip(depo_rates, depo_maturities)]

bond_helpers = []
for r, m,p in zip(bond_coupons, bond_maturities,bond_px):
    termination_date =  m
    schedule = ql.Schedule(calc_date,
                   termination_date,
                   coupon_frequency,
                   calendar,
                   bussiness_convention,
                   bussiness_convention,
                   ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
                   end_of_month)

    helper = ql.FixedRateBondHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(p)),
                                        settlement_days,
                                        face_amount,
                                        schedule,
                                        [r/100.0],
                                        day_count,
                                        bussiness_convention,
                                        )

    bond_helpers.append(helper)
    
rate_helpers = depo_helpers + bond_helpers
yieldcurve = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(calc_date,
                             rate_helpers,
                             day_count)
CurveHandle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(yieldcurve)

couponRate = cpn/100
coupons = [couponRate]
dayCount = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.Bond)
issueDate = ql.Date(iss_date.day, iss_date.month, iss_date.year)
maturityDate = ql.Date(mat_date.day, mat_date.month, mat_date.year)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
bussinessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False

schedule = ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, bussinessConvention,
                            bussinessConvention , dateGeneration, monthEnd)

fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlement_days, face_amount, schedule, coupons, dayCount)


spread1 = ql.SimpleQuote(bump/10000)
spread_handle1 = ql.QuoteHandle(spread1)
ts_spreaded1 = ql.ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(CurveHandle, spread_handle1)
ts_spreaded_handle1 = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ts_spreaded1)


bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(ts_spreaded_handle1)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)


# get spot rates
spots = []
pars = []
tenors = []
#for d in tqdm(base_curve.dates()[1:]):
curve_date = [to_qldate(x) for x in us_bus_day][5:]
for d in tqdm(curve_date):
    d_str = pd.Timestamp(d.year(), d.month(), d.dayOfMonth()).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    yrs = day_count.yearFraction(calc_date, d)
    compounding = ql.Compounded
    freq = ql.Semiannual
    zero_rate = base_curve.zeroRate(yrs, compounding, freq)
    tenors.append(yrs)
    eq_rate = zero_rate.equivalentRate(day_count,
                                       compounding,
                                       freq,
                                       calc_date,
                                       d).rate()

    par_bond = ust_curve.PriceFixedBond(base_curve_h,5,(pd.Timestamp(d_str) - pd.DateOffset(years= round((pd.Timestamp(d_str)-pd.Timestamp.today()).days/365)+1)).strftime("%Y%m%d"),\
                            d_str,\
                       face_amount = 100,settlement_days = 1,
                      dayCount = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.Bond),\
                      tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual),\
                       calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond),\
                      bussinessConvention = ql.Unadjusted,\
                      dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward,
                      monthEnd = False)
    pars.append(par_bond.bondYield( ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.Bond),ql.Compounded,ql.Semiannual)*100)
    
    spots.append(100*eq_rate)
spot_rate = pd.DataFrame({'Spot Rate':spots,'Par Rate':pars},index =tenors )
spot_rate['date'] = [qldate_to_pddate(x) for x in curve_date] #base_curve.dates()[1:]
spot_rate = spot_rate.set_index('date')
```

[image]